# Python script import fails if script is moved to subdirectory

Tags: python, virtualenv

This may be my own misunderstanding of how Python imports and search paths work, or it may be a problem in the packaging of the caldav package.

I have set up a virtualenv environment named myproject

In the top level of myproject, I have a script test.py which contains two imports:

```
import lxml
import caldav
```

In this directory, I type:

```
python test.py
```

and it works fine without any problem

Now I move the script to the subdirectory test and run the command:

```
python test/test.py
```

The import lxml seems to still work.  The import caldav fails with the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/test.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "test/test.py", line 29, in main
    exec ( "import " + modulename )
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/caldav2sql/myproject/test/caldav/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from davclient import DAVClient
  File "/home/ec2-user/caldav2sql/myproject/test/caldav/davclient.py", line 8, in <module>
    from caldav.lib import error
ImportError: No module named lib
```

Am I doing something wrong here?  Should I be setting up some kind of path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, `caldav` was in the same directory as `test.py`, so when you `import` it it worked fine. Now that you moved `test.py` to a subdirectory, your imports can't find it. You can either move `caldav` or set your [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

You could also modify your `sys.path`

Information from Python's module tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

> The variable sys.path is a list of strings that determines the interpreter’s search path for modules. It is initialized to a default path taken from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, or from a built-in default if PYTHONPATH is not set. You can modify it using standard list operations:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/ufs/guido/lib/python')
```

Comment: Since this is a virtualenv environment, caldav exists in myproject/lib/site-packages/caldav.  I tried setting PYTHONPATH to this location but it doesn't help.

Comment: I just found that there was a spurious installation of caldav under the test subdirectory, which was messing up everything.  I've accepted birryree's answer since it helped me find the root cause of the problem.  Thanks!